# "Variable not initialized" error

Tags: java, variables, popup, jmenuitem

I get this error when I tried to add a `ActionListener` to my `popupRequest` variable as shown in the code snippet.

> error: variable popupRequest might not have been initialized
>               popupRequest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>   1 error

So meaning to say my `popupRequest` isn't initialised and that is probably why the error is thrown. But the thing is I did initialise that variable.

**Code Snippet**

```
JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
JMenuItem popupTitle,popupHostJoin,popupRequest;
if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(evt)) {
        JL_CurrentUsers.setSelectedIndex(JL_CurrentUsers.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint()));
        popup.add(popupTitle = new JMenuItem("Private Message"));
        popup.addSeparator();
        if (nickname.equals(JL_CurrentUsers.getSelectedValue())) 
            popup.add(popupHostJoin = new JMenuItem("Host..."));
        else {
            popup.add(popupRequest = new JMenuItem("Request..."));//I initialise it here
            popup.add(popupHostJoin = new JMenuItem("Join..."));
        }

        popupHostJoin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new PvtMessageGUI(fHost,fPort,nickname).setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        //this is the line that gives me that error 
        popupRequest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.REQUEST,nickname+"->"+JL_CurrentUsers.getSelectedValue()));
            }
        });
        popup.show(JL_CurrentUsers,evt.getX(),evt.getY());
    }
```

I can work around it by initialising my `popupRequest` when i first declare the variable.

```
JMenuItem popupTitle,popupHostJoin,popupRequest=new JMenuItem("Request"...);
```

What I wanna know is.. **What is the difference between initialising my `popupRequest` when I declared it at the beginning, and initialising it inside my `if-else` statement?** And I don't see why the program didn't detect the initialised `popupRequest` but it did for the initialised `popupHostJoin` variable when I added the `ActionListener` to it.

Comment: You only assign a value to `popupRequest` if `nickname.equals(JL_CurrentUsers.getSelectedValue())` is false... what do you expect the value to be otherwise? It sounds like you should only add the action listener in that `if` branch...

Comment: check this for a clear explaination http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152351/java-error-variable-might-not-have-been-initialized#24152369

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize the variable in the `else` part only. In case the `if` condition is true (i.e. `nickname.equals(JL_CurrentUsers.getSelectedValue()` returns true), then `popupRequest` is never initialized. That's why the compiler throws the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (nickname.equals(JL_CurrentUsers.getSelectedValue())) 
            popup.add(popupHostJoin = new JMenuItem("Host..."));
        else {
            popup.add(popupRequest = new JMenuItem("Request..."));//I initialise it here
            popup.add(popupHostJoin = new JMenuItem("Join..."));
        }
```

if **nickname.equals(JL_CurrentUsers.getSelectedValue())** is false then the variable wont be initialized .