# Initializing an int variable before if statement

Tags: java

When compiling i get an Error stating that my variable has not been initialized.

Code :

```
    int number;
    if (dotted==true)
    {
        if (input >= 1 && input <= 21)
        {
            number = 1;
            System.out.print("True");
        }
        if (input >= 22 && input <= 40)
        {
            number = 2;
            System.out.print("False");
        }
        if (input >= 41 && input <= 63)
        {
            number = 3;
            System.out.print("False");
        }
        if (input >= 64 && input <= 82)
        {
            number = 4;
            System.out.print("True");
        }
  }
  else
  {
    if (input >= 2 && input <= 22)
        {
            number = 1;
            System.out.print("True");
        }
        if (input >= 23 && input <= 41)
        {
            number = 2;
            System.out.print("False");
        }
        if (input >= 42 && input <= 64)
        {
            number = 3;
            System.out.print("False");
        }
        if (input >= 65 && input <= 83)
        {
            number = 4;
            System.out.print("True");
        }
  }
System.out.print(number);  // number is not initialized?
```

Why is number not initialized?

I put int number = 0;
But then when i print, no matter the value of input it stays at 0?

Love how people downvote this. A student new to java with a question gets downvoted. Nice site

Comment: Well, what do you think the value of `number` is if `isValid` is not true?

Comment: because it's not. You can't just initialize it sometimes and then expect it to have something there everytime.

Comment: I have an else for the isValid being not true. How can i initialize this? because i need to print it later on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Error: variable might not have been initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152351/java-error-variable-might-not-have-been-initialized)

Comment: Those nested `if` statements don't make much sense. You're testing if `input == (an exact value)` and then additionally checking that it's less than a number that is larger, which is obviously unnecessary.

Comment: @4castle Looks like OPs actually wants ">=" instead of "==", but good find.

Comment: You have an else statement?  where?

Comment: Its in my code i just didn't think i needed to implement it here

Comment: Please read about how to write a [mcve].  If the code you post doesn't actually reflect what you're doing, the answers we give based on it won't be very useful.

Comment: I added my whole if/else.  The isValid is just a boolean statement that is working fine.

Comment: I wonder why you still ignore 4castles comment. Dare to read it? It tells you excaclty where your other issue is (which you should have find yourself by reading your code).

Comment: I did that still doesn't fix my problem

Comment: That means that `input` obviously doesn't match any of these ranges. Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: Input is a integer input that im prompting. When i run the program i make sure to enter an integer within this range.

Comment: Side note: `isValid==true` is redundant. You're comparing a `boolean` to a `boolean` to get the same `boolean` value back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `int number = 0` because you can't be sure whether the IF statement is executed or not. That's a precaution for your code.

Also, if you think about it, if it keeps being 0, it means you're actually not entering into the IF statement.

Try to put that and check if the `dotted` variable is actually TRUE or not.

Check also your variable `input`, because it is the one that changes your `number` variable.

Comment: I have an else statement which does the same thing, except isValid is false in that case. Yet it still stays 0

Comment: Can you please show me your else statement and/or your entire code? I'd like to help you better

Comment: I added my else statement, my whole code is very long.

Comment: Ok what about your variable "input"? How do you get it? Because if you don't get it in the right way, that could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is number not initialized?

Simply, because if none of the `if statements` are executed then the `number` variable will never get initialised. Hence the variable will not have a value and that's why you get the following error:

> When compiling i get an Error stating that my variable has not been
>   initialized.

Also, remember local variables must be initialized before the method exits.

with that in mind, you must at least give the variable below a default value:

```
int number = 0;
```

> I put int number = 0; But then when I print, no matter the value of
>   input it stays at 0?

if that's the case then it means you're never entering into the `if statement`. So, you might have to consider your `if statement` expressions again.

Comment: I did int number = 0;  but when i printed it later on, despite the value of input, it still printed 0?

Comment: that's because your if statements conditions valued to false.

Comment: I have an else statement which does the same thing, except isValid is false in that case. Yet it still stays 0

Comment: update your question with the full code. then i can see what the problem is.