# Pass variable outside of loop, Java

Tags: java, loops, variables, for-loop

I continue to get the error: variable V might not have been initialized. What am I doing wrong? I need to continue to work with the variable V outside of the loop. Is it possible to so this?

```
    String[] arr = _input.split(SEPARATOR);
    String[] V;
    int chunk = 1; // chunk size to divide
    for( int i=0;i<arr.length;i+=chunk){
        V = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i, Math.min(arr.length,i+chunk));
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(V));
```

Comment: array object v must be initialized first

Comment: Why are you copying the array in a loop?

Comment: The issue is because the compiler don't know if the loop will be skipped or not. This can be done just at runtime, so he warned you that you have a potential uninitialized variable, with the connected runtime issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Error: variable might not have been initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152351/java-error-variable-might-not-have-been-initialized)

Comment: you have to set String[] V = null in the decleration. As Mario Santini said there may be case which will not enter the loop

Answer (score 1):

simply assign it inital with `null`:

```
String[] V = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize the local variables before using it. Try this instead of `String[] V;`

```
String[] V = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not sure that you go into the loop. In that case `V` really is not initialized. Init the variable first `String[] V = new String[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Array object **V**  must be initialized first

try doing

```
String[] V = null;
```

and give the array a more descriptive name... and follow oracle name conventions

Answer (score 0):

Set `String[] v=null;`

also why you are coping the array in a loop??