# what is wrong with this program? variable character might not have been initialized

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I made a program to reverse entered characters, and every time I run it I had an error message. what is my mistake and what is this error message mean ?!

```
import java.util.*;

/* it's a program reverses entered characters */
class rev
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=1,n=0;
        char[] character;
         while (i!=100) {
character[i]=sc.next().charAt(0);
         n++;
         if (character[i]=='\n') {
         break;}
         i++;
     }
     for (i=n;i>=1;i--){
       System.out.print(character[i]);
     }
    }
}
```

> error: variable character might not have been initialized
>   character[i]=sc.next().charAt(0);
>   ^
>   error: variable character might not have been initialized
>   System.out.print(character[i]);

Comment: First, don't try to *run* the code until it's compiled. Next, the error message is telling you *exactly* what the error is. Where do you believe you're initializing the `character` variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Error: variable might not have been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152351/java-error-variable-might-not-have-been-initialized)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, "variable character might not have been initialized." I.e., you have char[] character, but never assigned anything to it. Try adding:

char[] character = char[100];

Of course, 100 might not be the value you need, that depends on what you expect to read in.

Comment: tell them to change the while condition from != to a <